# Incorrect data displayed in html table

Tags: php, html

My output does not insert the data for `Total Marks` correctly, it seems like it is missing the total marks for question 1, This is because the marks for each question goes like this:

```
Question 1: 3
Question 2: 5
Question 3: 2
```

Now the table contains incorrect answers so the table looks like this fiddle which I have found http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7j1-we2, if you look at the results, you realize that both question 1 and 2 contain question 2 marks and that queston 3 contains its marks. But how can I get the correct marks to be display, why is it missing the first question marks?

**UPDATE 1:**

```
$query = "SELECT q.QuestionNo, an.Answer, q.TotalMarks, o.OptionType
FROM 
Question q INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionID = an.QuestionID
INNER JOIN Option_Table o ON o.OptionID = q.OptionID
ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer
   ";

   // prepare query
   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
   // execute query
   $stmt->execute(); 


       // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionNo = array();
    $totalMarks = array();
    $incorrect_ans = array();


    // Fetch the results into an array

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbQuestionNo, $dbAnswer, $dbTotalMarks $dbOptionType);

$specialOptionTypes = array('Yes or No' => array( 'Yes', 'No' ),'True or False' => array( 'True', 'False' ));

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

// Do this for each row:
if ( array_key_exists( $dbOptionType, $specialOptionTypes ) ) {
    $options = $specialOptionTypes[$dbOptionType];
} else if ( preg_match( '/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $dbOptionType, $match ) ) {
    $options = range( $match[1], $match[2] );
} else {
    // issue warning about unrecognized option type
    $options = array();
}
$right = str_split( $dbAnswer ); 
$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right );  

        $searchQuestionNo[] = $dbQuestionNo;
        $totalMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks;
      }
```

Above is the code which retrieves the wrong answers. What happens is for each question, it retireves each questions `$dbOptionType` and display the list of possible answers. So for example if question 1's `$dbOptionType` is `A - D`, then the list of `Answers` it displays is `A, B, C, D`. Also the code above retrieves each question number and total marks using `$dbQuestionNo` and `$TotalMarks`.

If a question has multiple answers though, it displays two sets of answers and removes 1 answer from a set. This is because in the database, to recieve correct answer for a question which has multiple answers and single answers it is like this:

```
QuestionNo  Answer  TotalMarks OptionType
1           B       3          A-D
2           A       5          A-D
2           C       5          A-D
3           D       2          A-D
```

**UPDATE 2:**

For question 2 as it is multiple answers, that is why it is displays two sets of data in the arrays. Beause the way it is removing a correct answer if there are multiple answers in a question is as so:

```
Question 2: Answers: A, B, C, D  Remove Correct Answer: A  Incorrect Answers: B, C, D
Question 2: Answers: A, B, C, D  Remove Correct Answer: C  Incorrect Answers: A, B, D
```

The way it is removing correct answers if a question has multiple correct answers is above. It is:

- Displaying Possible Answers
- Removes 1 Correct Answer `A`
- Displays Incorrect Answers `B, C, D`

To Remove second correct Answer it repeats the process:

- Displaying Possible Answers
- Removes 1 Correct Answer `C`
- Displays Incorrect Answers `A, C, D` (We know `A` is not correct but because it is only removing one correct answer at a time and displays all possible answers, it acts as if `A` is incorrect in second set but correct in first set)

UPDATE 3:

The error is caused by the fact that array you are iterating over $ques_ans with for() has a gap in keys.

```
var_dump($ques_ans) gives us:
array(3) {
  ... skipped for brevity
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "B"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "D"
  }
  ... skipped for brevity
}
```

There is no element with the key [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNjty.png). It's because the function array_intersect, which I use on line 49, preserves keys.

To quickly fix code just to make it work without errors I added array_values() on line 51:
`$ques_ans[$questionNo] = array_values($q_incorrect_ans);    //store the array of incorrect ans` against the ques no as key.

But I still get the odd gap in `$keys`.

**HERE IS THE CODE:**

Below is code:

```
   $query = "SELECT q.SessionId, s.SessionName, q.QuestionId, q.QuestionNo, q.QuestionContent, an.Answer, an.AnswerId, q.QuestionMarks, q.OptionId, o.OptionType 
FROM  
Question q INNER JOIN Answer an ON q.QuestionID = an.QuestionID 
INNER JOIN Option_Table o ON o.OptionID = q.OptionID 
INNER JOIN Session s ON s.Sessionid = q.Sessionid 
WHERE s.SessionName = ? 
ORDER BY q.QuestionId, an.Answer 
   "; 

   // prepare query 
   $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query); 
   // You only need to call bind_param once 
   $stmt->bind_param("s", $assessment); 
   // execute query 
   $stmt->execute();  


       // This will hold the search results 
    $searchQuestionNo = array(); 
    $searchQuestionContent = array(); 
    $totalMarks = array(); 
    $searchAnswerId = array(); 
    $incorrect_ans = array(); 
    $searchMarks = array(); 

    // Fetch the results into an array 

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db) 
$stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionNo, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbAnswerId, $dbQuestionMarks, $dbOptionId, $dbOptionType); 

$specialOptionTypes = array('Yes or No' => array( 'Yes', 'No' ),'True or False' => array( 'True', 'False' )); 

while ($stmt->fetch()) { 

// Do this for each row: 
if ( array_key_exists( $dbOptionType, $specialOptionTypes ) ) { 
    $options = $specialOptionTypes[$dbOptionType]; 
} else if ( preg_match( '/^([A-Z])-([A-Z])$/', $dbOptionType, $match ) ) { 
    $options = range( $match[1], $match[2] ); 
} else { 
    // issue warning about unrecognized option type 
    $options = array(); 
} 
$right = str_split( $dbAnswer );  
$wrong = array_diff( $options, $right );   

        $searchQuestionNo[] = $dbQuestionNo; 
        $searchQuestionContent[] = $dbQuestionContent; 
        $incorrect_ans[] = $wrong; 
        $searchAnswerId[] = $dbAnswerId; 
        $totalMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks; 
        $searchMarks[] = $dbQuestionMarks; 
      }     

?> 



</head> 

<body> 

<?php

$ques_ans = array(); //to store incorrect answers against ques no.

$q_occ_count = array_count_values($searchQuestionNo);
foreach ($searchQuestionNo as $key => $questionNo) {
    if (!array_key_exists($questionNo, $ques_ans)) {
        if ($q_occ_count[$questionNo] === 1) //if a ques has only one correct ans
            {
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = $incorrect_ans[$key]; //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key 
        } else //if a ques has more than 1 correct ans
            {
            //find the intersection of incorrect_ans arrays for this ques
            $q_keys          = array_keys($searchQuestionNo, $questionNo);
            $q_incorrect_ans = $incorrect_ans[$q_keys[0]];
            foreach ($q_keys as $q_key) {
                $q_incorrect_ans = array_intersect($q_incorrect_ans, $incorrect_ans[$q_key]);
            }
            $ques_ans[$questionNo] = array_values($q_incorrect_ans); //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key
        }
    }
}
var_dump($ques_ans);
?> 
<table id='penaltytbl'> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th> 
<th class='questionth'>Question</th> 
<th class='incorrectanswerth'>Incorrect Answer</th> 
<th class='answermarksth'>Marks per Answer</th> 
<th class='totalmarksth'>Total Marks</th> 
<th class='noofmarksth'>Marks Remaining</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<?php

foreach ($ques_ans as $questionNo => $inc_ans) {
    $q_row_span = count($inc_ans);
    $row_count  = 0;

?> 

<tr class="questiontd"> 

<td class="questionnumtd q<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php
    echo $q_row_span;
?>"><?php
    echo $questionNo;
?> 
<input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="q<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>_ans_org" class="q<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>_ans_org" value="<?php
    echo $searchMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)];
?>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="q<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>_ans" class="q<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>_ans" value="<?php
    echo $searchMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)];
?>"> 
    </td> 

    <td class="questioncontenttd" rowspan="<?php
    echo $q_row_span;
?>"><?php
    echo $searchQuestionContent[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)];
?> </td> 

<td class="answertd"><?php
    echo $inc_ans[$row_count];
?> 
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[]" value="<?php
    echo $inc_ans[$row_count];
?>"> 
</td> 

<td class="answermarkstd"> 
<input class="individualMarks q<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" data-qnum="<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" /> 
</td> 


<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="<?php
    echo $q_row_span;
?>"><?php
    echo $totalMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)];
?></td> 

<td class="noofmarkstd q<?php
    echo $questionNo;
?>_ans_text"  q_group="1" rowspan="<?php
    $q_row_span;
?>"><?php
    echo "<strong>" . $searchMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)] . "</strong>";
?></td> 
</tr> 
    <?php
    //remaining incorrect answers in separate row (if any) follows here
    if ($row_count < $q_row_span - 1) {
        for ($i = ($row_count + 1); $i < $q_row_span; $i++) {
?>         
            <tr> 
            <td class="answertd"><?php
            echo $inc_ans[$i];
?> 
            <input type="hidden" id="hiddenincorrect" name="incorrect[]" value="<?php
            echo $inc_ans[$i];
?>"> 
            </td> 

            <td class="answermarkstd"> 
            <input class="individualMarks q<?php
            echo $questionNo;
?>_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" data-qnum="<?php
            echo $questionNo;
?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" /> 
            </td> 
            </tr> 
    <?php
        }
    }
}

?> 
</tbody> 
</table> 

<p> 
<input type='hidden' id='num_groups' name='num_groups' value='<?php
echo $questionNo;
?>'> 
<input id="submitBtn" name="submitPenalty" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" /> 
</p> 

</form>
```

**SCREENSHOT:**

[image]

Comment: How are you finding the wrong answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are retrieving the total marks. You are accessing `$totalMarks` with `$questionNo` as index, but should use the actual array index for that question.

Working code:

```
<td class="totalmarkstd" rowspan="<?php echo $q_row_span?>">
    <?php echo $totalMarks[array_search($questionNo, $searchQuestionNo)]?>
</td>
```

Update 1:

```
$ques_ans[$questionNo] = array_values($q_incorrect_ans);    //store the array of incorrect ans against the ques no as key
```

Update 2:

Use array_values.

```
foreach($ques_ans as $questionNo => $inc_ans)
{
    $inc_ans = array_values($inc_ans);
```

Updated phpFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps

Comment: The array is just a set up on how the result are being retrieved. I will display you the code which shows how the arrays are being formed, give me 5 mins

Comment: Just testing your answer, I believe it works but just making sure

Comment: For some strange reason it is missing a correct answer for question 2. Correct answers is `B` and `D` but it only shows answer `B`, it displays a blank for answer `D`

Comment: I will update php fiddle, it seems like when I add extra columns to table then it provides a problem

Comment: Ignore the arrau under `QuestionContent` because it works in application. But if you look under `Incorrect Answer` column in results, you see it is missing an `Incorrect Answer` which is `D`. Also how can I get `Marks Remaining` column to be display like the `Total Marks` column where data is in middle with no show of table cell? http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps

Comment: You are not updating `$row_count` properly. First design your application before diving into code.

Comment: That is the issue I am actually to sort now but struggling to see where I am going wrong with `$row_count`

Comment: Nope can't seem figure it out, have you got any idea on updating the $row_count correctly?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Update your high level requirement in the question.

Comment: I will update question but the only problem is that it is missing an answer. What I am trying to do is show ecah question's details and incorrect answers per question.

Comment: I am trying to create a negative marking page where the user can give marks to drop for each incorrect answer per question. This is so that if a student is cheating, then they will penalised for each incorrect answer they give by taking away marks for each incorrect answer. In the table in the fiddle what you are seeing for each question is only the incorrect answers. The correct answers in each question are removed.

Comment: But like I said problem with question 2 in table is that it is missing an incorrect answer, it is only doing it for question 2 as this question actually has multiple correct answers, so like you mentioned there is sometihng wrong with `$row_count` but don't know what it should be set to, to fix it

Comment: Ok, why is there two arrays corresponding to question 2? Why are these different?

Comment: @I included an updated fiddle in one of the comments. I will include update on reason why 2 sets of data are showin in array, look at update in 10 mins, I will test your fix

Comment: Is there a better way for me to use the array interset so that instead of displaying multiple sets of arrays for a question which has multiple answers, it is able to just have 1 set of array and remove the multiple correct answers in a question in one set. This is because I tested you fix with a different set of questions and answers and even that one has an incorrect answer missing

Comment: Can you show me the issue? What do you mean by multiple set of answers? Where are you displaying them?

Comment: Look at `UPDATE 1:` section in code. You see I have a query, the query results are show below block of code, the query shows each correct answer per question. Look at question 2 in query results, it has 2 answers (in other words multiple correct answers), the other questions just has a single correct answer. In bottom block of code under query you see how I have tried to remove the correct answers from the rest of the answers (the rest of the answers are incorrect). Its the same issue, I can't show you anymore coz I have shown you the whole code.

Comment: Best thng I can do is just create another fiddle which contains a different set of incorrect answers in the table so you can see what is happening. Give me 5 mins

Comment: What I am asking is not what you have, but what should your output be? Draw up an image of your expected output.

Comment: It keeps refreshing when I am using the phpfiddle, I can't wait to get back to India and relax back at home. Look all I can ask from you is change my code so that if a question has multiple correct answers, it will display only one set of incorrect answers with the correct answers already removed from that set. That is my question

Comment: The output you have in the php fiddle is fine, but when I tried a different set of answers, it just messes up and some incorrect answers are missing from the table. In your phpfiddle you have all the rows filled under `Incorrect Answer` column, in mine they are all not filled, some rows under that column are missing values

Comment: Look at `UPDATE 3` in question, you will understand what problem is

Comment: Just give me your phpFiddle which is not working and let me see.

Comment: Updated fiddle, http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/get-rps, you see the thing is that it works in the fiddle as all incorrect answers are displayed. But in my application it doesn't work as one incorrect answer is missing. I am going to send you a link to the application. You will need to login , I will send that to you by email so you can see the problem.

Comment: One quick fix, you dont need array for your questions?

Comment: What do you mean by "one incorrect answer is missing" ? Can you update the phpFiddle with your live data?

Comment: The phpfiddle does contain the latest data, I have got, but like I said it works in fiddle but not in my application. Did you recieve my email so that you can access the page itself, you then should be able to see what is happening in the page. What I will do is that in my question under `Here is the Code` section,  I will paste the actual code I am using in the application where it recieves it from the database. Only way you can see where data is coming from properly

Comment: So, you have a database, you get the data from DB, right? So, you are saying the data you get is having issue? Or is the same data shows properly in fiddle, but wrong in application?

Comment: Yes the same data is working in the fiddle but not in the application. The correct answers and the option type are retrieved from the database. Then I use php to display the list of answers (or list of options in other words) depending on the `OptionType` from the db and I retrieve the correct answers from the `Answer` field in the db and remove them using php from the list of answers (options)

Comment: I checked the link, it doesn't show any data, just blank headings only. Is the server able to access your DB?

Comment: Yeah I was worried that was going to happen, thing is that you have to complete some pages before accessing that page. I will provide a screenshot on what I am seeing at moment so you can see what is happening. I have posted my full code as mentioned in `Here is the code` section so you can see the whole code. Give me 2 mins for screenshot

Comment: screenshot included by the way if you didnt notice it

Comment: Please show me the line of code that prints out the echo. Which variable is it?

Comment: `<?php echo$inc_ans[$i];?>`

Comment: Ok seems like it is looking ok, just need to test another set of answers, but just need to test with another set of answers. I will let you know

Comment: Im just trying to sort a little issue out. I will let you know. Also because you helped me so much I will set this question as a bounty and award you a 50 points bounty

Comment: No need for bounties... you only have 75 to start with :)

Comment: It works, the only issue I am having is if an option is true or false or yes or no as it displays both correct and incorrect answers but it is nothing to do with this question. Actually my friend I am working with has posted that question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337345/do-not-want-to-display-two-sets-of-values-in-an-array)if you want another challenge ;) Thanks again, and looking good for our lot against england in the cricket :)