# How to display correct number in alert

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am having issue with a question number displayed in an alert. Instead of displaying the question number, it is displaying the question id as the question number. So in the alert validation it states for example:

```
You have errors on question number: 115
```

When it should say `You have errors on question number: 3` for example

Now this code display question id: `value="<?php echo$questionId?>"`

This code display question number: `echo$searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]`

But when I tried to do this:

```
<input type='hidden' id='num_groups' name='num_groups' value='<?php echo$searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]`?>'>
```

It does not display question number for jquery alert. To be honest what happens is that the validation doesn't work as it doesn't appear. Yet if I kept the above code to what it was which value was the question id:

```
<input type='hidden' id='num_groups' name='num_groups' value='<?php echo$questionId?>'>
```

Then it displays the questionId in the alert and the alert actually works.

So my question is how do I include the question number value in the alert yet be able to get the validation to work as well, like it does for questionid?

Below is main code so you can see where everything comes from:

**PHP:**

```
    <?

       // This will hold the search results
    $searchQuestionId = array();
    $searchQuestionNo = array();

    // Fetch the results into an array

   // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbQuestionId, $dbQuestionNo, $dbQuestionContent, $dbAnswer, $dbAnswerId, $dbQuestionMarks, $dbOptionId, $dbOptionType);


        $searchQuestionId[] = $dbQuestionId;
        $searchQuestionNo[] = $dbQuestionNo;
      } 

?>



</head>

<body>


<form id="PenaltyMarks" action="<?php echo htmlentities($action); ?>" method="post">


<?php

$ques_ans = array();    //to store incorrect answers against ques no.

$q_occ_count = array_count_values($searchQuestionId);
foreach($searchQuestionId as $key => $questionId)
{
.....
}


?>
<table id='penaltytbl'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class='questionth'>Question No.</th>
<th class='questionth'>Question</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($ques_ans as $questionId => $inc_ans)
{


?>

<tr class="questiontd">

<td class="questionnumtd q<?php echo$searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]?>_qnum" rowspan="<?php echo$q_row_span?>"><?php echo$searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]?>
<input type="hidden" name="numQuestion" value="<?php echo$questionId?>" />
    </td>


<td class="answermarkstd">
<input class="individualMarks q<?php echo$questionId?>_mark"  q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" data-qnum="<?php echo$questionId?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" />
</td>

</tr>
<?php
}

?>
</tbody>
</table>

<p>
<input type='hidden' id='num_groups' name='num_groups' value='<?php echo$questionId?>'>
<input id="submitBtn" name="submitPenalty" type="submit" value="Submit Marks" />
</p>

</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
  < script type = "text/javascript" >


    myClickHandler = function (e) {
      var ng = $('#num_groups').val();
      for (var group = 1; group 
           <= ng; group++) {
        if (!validation(group)) return false;
      }

    });


    function validation(group) {
      var msg = [];

      var nb = 0; // Number of blank values
      $("input[data-qnum='" + group + "']").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          nb++;
          return false;
        }
      });
      if (nb != 0) {
        msg.push("\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Penalty Marks textbox \n");
      }

      if (msg.length >
          0) {
        alert("You have errors on Question Number: " + group + "\n\n" + msg.join("\n"));
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }




    < /script>
```

Comment: Please consider some of these suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14305295/285587 **especially in the part regarding deleting the question and asking it again**

Comment: Can you do a phpFiddle for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that, as you said, this code permits to retieve the question number :

```
echo$searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]
```

---

Add your question number as an attribute `q_number` in your input element :

```
<input class="individualMarks q<?php echo$questionId?>_mark" q_number="<?php echo $searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]; ?>" q_group="1" name="answerMarks[]" type="text" data-type="qmark" data-qnum="<?php echo$questionId?>" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" maxlength="3" value="0" />
```

And use it in your `validation` function

```
function validation(group) {
  var msg = [];

  var qNumber = null;

  var nb = 0; // Number of blank values
  $("input[data-qnum='" + group + "']").each(function () {

    //Assign the question number
    qNumber = $(this).attr('q_number');

    if ($(this).val() == '') {
      nb++;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if (nb != 0) {
    msg.push("\u2022 You have not entered in a value in all the Penalty Marks textbox \n");
  }

  //Use qNumber instead of the group variable
  if (msg.length > 0) {
    alert("You have errors on Question Number: " + qNumber + "\n\n" + msg.join("\n"));
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it hasn't worked it is doing the same thing what it is doing. When I try to change code to display question number like in my attempt and like what you tried in your answer, when I have a text input which is blank for `.individualMarks`, instead of display the error message that not entered in value in all penalty Marks, it passes the validation goes straight to the confirmation.

Comment: Try to debug your code using the console (F12) and place a break point in your click handler function.

Comment: This is first time trying to debug using f12 so bear with me, it highlights the `return false` in the else statement in the click handler function. In the `scope variables` section it states `e: jQuery.Event
group: 6
ng: "5"
this: form#PenaltyMarks` I don't know if this is relevant

Comment: Check this link : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints The debugger will permit to find out the problem. Use break points and step by step functionnality

Comment: Ok thanks for the link, Im assuming my previous comment didn't help you then?

Comment: Oh no it is only going to the `return false` after I click on the `Cancel` button, but when the confirmation appears, there is no breakpoint shown

Comment: it is strange, the validation works for `echo $questionId` but when echo is `echo$searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]` then validation doesn't work. And `echo$searchQuestionNo[array_search($questionId, $searchQuestionId)]` is legit, it does work when display question number in the table. Just validation doesn't work when I want to include question number in the alert in the validation